# Using a custom field inside a shortocde

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, plugin-nextgen-gallery

Im trying to use a custom field inside a shortocde for a nextgen gallery slider on a page. The goal is to change the gallery id by entering in the corresponding id on page creation with a custom field. This doesn't seem to be working how I have it setup though and is just calling all images which makes me thing no value for the gallery id is being called.

```
<?php
  global $image_gallery; 
  $image_gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image_gallery', TRUE); 
?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[jj-ngg-image-list html_id="about-image-list" gallery="return $image_gallery" max_pictures="4" width="160" height="150" orientation="horizontal"]'); ?>
<?php ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you pass the variable using normal php string concatenation:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[jj-ngg-image-list html_id="about-image-list" gallery="' . $image_gallery . '" max_pictures="4" width="160" height="150" orientation="horizontal"]'); ?>
```

Comment: please mark the answer so others can find solutions for similars problems